# Is it possible to retrieve x or y without altering Pos class

Tags: java, coordinates

I'm working on a homework assignment regarding a maze of boolean values. The goal is basically to find the shortest path from start to finish if it exists. That's something I think I can handle. But!

We have been given a class called Pos that handles positions in the maze. And this is where my question comes in:

This is the class:

```
public class Pos implements Comparable<Pos>{
    public int x, y;

    Pos(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int compareTo(Pos p){
        return (this.x != p.x ? this.x - p.x : this.y - p.y);
    }

}
```

The maze solver is gonna be like this:

```
public ArrayList<Pos> solve(Pos start, Pos finish, boolean maze[][])
```

Now what I was thinking about doing is getting the coordinates from start and finish and store them in variables when searching through the maze. Like `startX` and `startY`.

But here's the problem. I am wondering if this is possible without altering the Pos class? I'm not sure if I'm allowed to add `getX()` and `getY()` to the Pos class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With this implementation you can simply access the instance variables `x,y` because they are declared as public.

Comment: God damn, now I feel stupid. I always think too complicated about how to solve stuff. Thanks btw!

Comment: np, maybe not in this case, but FYI and your future experience, having public fields can lead to strange class behaviour, it's a good practice to have private fields and make getters or setters to those fields which can be changed externally. (Additionaly, if you wouldn't have access to the `x,y` (not public, no getter/setter) than take a look at Java Reflection API (that sh*t is crazy, but commonly, if reflection can be avoided, don't use it ;) )